# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't start after installing with LiveUSB

Tags: 12.04, installation

I installed Ubuntu with my LiveUSB, and it said to restart in order to use your system, so I restarted. Now, I am just stuck in a completely black screen with a blinking `_` underscore cursor.

I have already waited 10 minutes for something to happen, but there is no response from the computer.

I don't know what the problem could be, but maybe the message I got during installation that said `APT couldn't be configured, so no additional apps will be installed` was the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Purge and reinstall GRUB, following instructions [HERE](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099)

Source: I had the same problem.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I did that and now when I start it says 'error:no video mode activated.' What now?

Answer (score 0):

As a tip , i have the same problem but by pressing the space key multiples times it does boot and show me the ubuntu startup logo....

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But it now gives me the error: 'init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job' How to fix this?

Comment: this is one of bugs from 12.04 ( check google ) but i do advise you to repair the grub : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099

Answer (score 0):

this is one of bugs from 12.04 ( check google ) but i do advise you to repair the grub : [ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099) –  that should fix it!

Comment: I already repaired that for the second time, still not working. And does that mean that 12.04 wont work for me now or what? Shall I try reinstalling?

Comment: does 11.10 work for you? was it an update? more info please? do you other boot?

Comment: Yes, I already used 11.10 for three months. I deleted it and installed 12.04 fresh with a liveusb, so no update. I don't have any other os now. My PC is an acer aspire one netbook.

Comment: I reinstalled it now and did the same things again, but I have the failed to create pty error again -.- I'm really disappointed of this new version. 11.10 had no problems.

Comment: I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 3 times, repairing grub 5 times, every time I had the same problem. Shall I try to use a LiveCD?